# what type of memory do registers have?

Tags: memory, cpu-registers

Accumulator(AC), Data Register(DR), Address Register(AR), Program Counter(PC), Memory Data Register (MDR), Index Register(IR), Memory Buffer Register(MBR)

these are different registers in a compute.
what type of memory are they? random access, read only, or any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what type of memory are they?

Registers do not have memory. Registers are storage locations within the CPU.

> these are different registers in a computer?

The register set varies among processors.

> random access, read-only, or any other?

General purpose registers are read/write. However, there are registers that are generally read only. The processor status register is usually read-only in the sense that you cannot write to it. However, you can change its value through instructions. Some processors might have write-only registers.